# Numerical integral of a vector of discrete points

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences

I was trying to obtain the integral of a vector of discrete points (with MATLAB), that do not follow a known function. For instance, I have a vector with discrete points defining a sine function and I want as output a vector of discrete points defining a (-) cosine function.

My idea was to implement the inverse thing of finite differences, solving a linear system in which I know the derivatives writing it in matrix form (A*x=b).

Example with 4th order central scheme, handling the edges with second order schemes, one-sided and central.

```
A = zeros(length(b), length(b));

A(1, 1:3) = [-3 4 -1] ./ (2*dx); % Fwd 2nd order
A(2, 1:3) = [-1 0 1] ./ (2*dx); % Central 2nd order

for ii = 3 : length(b) - 2
    A(ii, (1:5)+ii-3) = [1 -8 0 8 -1] ./ (12*dx); % Central 4th order
end
A(end-1, end-2:end) = [-1 0 1] ./ (2*dx); % Central 2nd order
A(end, end-2:end) = [1 -4 3] ./ (2*dx); % Bwd 2nd order

x = A \ b; % Solves the linear system
```

I'm getting singular or near-singular matrix.
I'm not mathematician and I don't really know if this makes sense, but I think it should.

(Maybe BCs needed for this to work?)

Any ideas for fixing this or another approach are highly appreciated!
Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you could figure out how to make this work, it will take about $n^2$ times longer than it should where $n$ is your number of data points. Just use a standard quadrature rule. For second order the trapezoidal rule will do the job. For fourth order the Simpson rule will do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very familiar with the quadrature rule. As far as I understand in order to use 'quad' function in MATLAB, you need the function as an input, and it is something I do not have, I have to work just with a vector of measurements. 

The matrix becomes non-singular when you apply a BC, for example I know that my first value of the integral is always going to be 0 (for my purposes), so writing instead:

b(1) = 0;
A(1, 1) = 1; %BC

Works the way I want, I don't understand the mathematical reason behind it, but I remembered something similar from a CFD course.

Comment: "Quadrature rule" is just a way of referring to conventional numerical integration routines. There is no good reason to solve a linear system at all. For instance if I had uniformly spaced data in a vector y where the spacing is dx, I would just use: dx\*(sum(y)-y(1)/2-y(end)/2) This implements the trapezoidal rule. If you instead need the values of the antiderivative which vanishes at the left endpoint, then you can use dx\*(cumsum(y)-y(1)/2-y/2).

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution! That was what I was looking for at the beginning but I didn't know how and I tried to implement the other approach with finite differences since I am more familiar with them. In case anyone is curious, the 'same' results are obtained with both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is singular for the same reason that the derivative operation is non-invertible: it has a nontrivial nullspace, the space of constant functions. Primitive functions are only defined up to a constant term.

You can likely fix this by using the pseudoinverse (matlab pinv), which will give you the least-norm solution of your underdetermined equations.

Or use a quadrature rule, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will take a look at the pseudoinverse concept out of curiosity.

Comment: Matlab's backslash will give the same solution as the pseudoinverse would give anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested, I got the best results with MATLAB by first detrending the vector and then using cumtrapz which I guess it is equivalent to the usage of cumsum described by Ian above.

```
cumtrapz(detrend(b,'constant'))
```